# How to add numbers in unix using loop for command?

Tags: unix, for-loop

Could someone please help me out with loop problem. I need it to display the total of all the numbers. This is what i have tried so far:

```
sum=0  
for numbers in 6 9 -4 7   
do   
   sum=$(($sum+$numbers))    
echo $sum 
done
```

The output shows these numbers:

```
6  
15   
11   
18
```

Comment: Are you only wanting to echo the final output? Don't print inside the loop, and just add to $sum. echo $sum outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `echo $sum` outside of the `for loop` to display the final value, instead of displaying its running value from within the loop.

```
sum=0
for numbers in 6 9 -4 7
do
sum=$(($sum+$numbers))
done
echo $sum
```